# Debugear código Django utilizando Docker

Tags: django, linux, docker, debian, pycharm

Les cuento.
Estoy realizando un proyecto en Django, utilizo PyCharm en Windows 8.1. Para levantar el servidor web y la base de datos utilizo Docker instalado en Debian (Linux) a traves de una maquina virtual (no instale Docker de Windows por un problemas de compatibilidad). El problema es que al trabajar de esta manera, no encuentro la forma de poder debugear el código (poner puntos de interrupcion y demás).

Estuve buscando por todos lados pero no encontre ninguna solución. Tal vez alguno pudo resolver este problema.

Por las dudas dejo el archivo `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
db:
 image: postgres
 container_name: csuperior-postgres
 environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: xxxxxxx
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxxxxxx
broker:
 image: rabbitmq
 container_name: csuperior-broker
 environment:
  - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=xxxxxxx
  - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=xxxxxxx
web:
 container_name: csuperior-web
 volumes:
  - .:/code/
 build: .
 ports:
   - '8000:8000'
 command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
 depends_on:
  - db
  - broker
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: lo que quieres hacer al hacer el debugger es imposible, recuerda que docker te genera un contenedor y luego lo publicas , a lo mucho puedes acceder a los logs de docker-compose el comando util para esto seria `docker-compose logs <contenedor>`

Answer (score 0):

No se si te sirva la opción que yo utilizo, como Python tiene muchas herramientas de introspección me ayudo un poco de ellas para verificar el valor de las variables u objetos en cualquier momento:

```py
python manage.py runserver
```

Esto te deja mostrando los logs de tu server y pues en tu código para obtener los datos de un objeto en particular puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```py
print("Tag: tracking",myobject.__dict__)
print(dir(myobject))
```

Eso de forma instantanea al hacer las peticiones en tu código lo podrás ir viendo, no creo que sea la mejor forma pero es la que me ha funcionado en Docker, he debugeado apps muy grandes con el uso de introspección solo que es maś entretenido y requiere mucho esfuerzo.

Si no tienes otra opción puedes utilizarla.